# Draw lines with custom thickness with Pyglet/OpenGL?

Tags: python, opengl, line, pyglet

I've drawn a rectangle (4 line segments), but they're too thin. How can I change the thickness of each line?

The following example of mine gives me this:

[image]

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    game_area = None

    labels = [pyglet.text.Label("0"*8,
              font_name = "Times New Roman",
              font_size=18,
              color = (255, 0, 0, 255),
              x = app.width // 2, 
              y = app.height // 2 - n,
              anchor_x = "center", 
              anchor_y = "center") for n in range(0, 100, 18)]

    @app.event
    def on_draw():
        app.clear()
        [label.draw() for label in labels]
        pyglet.graphics.draw(4, pyglet.gl.GL_LINES, 
            ("v2f", (0, 0, 0, app.height, app.width / 2, app.height, app.width / 2, 0))
        )

    pyglet.app.run()
```

Answer (score 8):

You can change the width of lines by calling [glLineWidth](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glLineWidth.xhtml). This is accomplished through pyglet like so:

```
pyglet.gl.glLineWidth(desired_line_size)
```

If you require lines of varying thickness you'll have to call the function again with the new thickness before drawing each line. Otherwise, you can just set the thickness in your initialization and leave it be.

Comment: Looks like this also works with the current version of pyglet, when you use its newer [shapes api](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/shapes.html), although it might not be a feature to mix gl primitives with usage of those higher level pyglet class (I wouldn't know) but perhaps more of a behavior that seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

I've realized that actually I have to draw triangles in order to achieve "thickness":

```
def draw_game_area():
        pyglet.graphics.draw(24, pyglet.gl.GL_TRIANGLES, 
            ("v2f", (ORIGIN, ORIGIN, ORIGIN, app.height, LINE_SEGMENT_THICKNESS, ORIGIN,
                     ORIGIN, app.height, LINE_SEGMENT_THICKNESS, app.height, LINE_SEGMENT_THICKNESS, ORIGIN,
                     ORIGIN, ORIGIN, ORIGIN, LINE_SEGMENT_THICKNESS, app.width / 2, ORIGIN,
                     ORIGIN, LINE_SEGMENT_THICKNESS, app.width / 2, LINE_SEGMENT_THICKNESS, app.width / 2, ORIGIN,
                     app.width / 2 - LINE_SEGMENT_THICKNESS, app.height, app.width / 2, app.height, app.width / 2, ORIGIN,
                     app.width / 2 - LINE_SEGMENT_THICKNESS, app.height, app.width / 2, ORIGIN, app.width / 2 - LINE_SEGMENT_THICKNESS, ORIGIN,
                     ORIGIN, app.height, app.width / 2, app.height, app.width / 2, app.height - LINE_SEGMENT_THICKNESS,
                     ORIGIN, app.height, ORIGIN, app.height - LINE_SEGMENT_THICKNESS, app.width / 2, app.height - LINE_SEGMENT_THICKNESS))
        )
```

[image]

Comment: Well, absolutely a +1 for the maths (though I dare you to write the code for a rotated rectangle ). But are you sure your OpenGL interface does not include [`glLineWidth`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glLineWidth.xhtml)?

Comment: Late to the party, but you could just draw two `pyglet.gl.GL_QUADS` (rectangles) on top of each other or 4 separate ones.

Answer (score 2):

Create points and draw a polygon between them to create the desired thickness.
I created a [function on desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/t1vg34zpmm) which takes two points and finds new points to create the desired thickness `T`.

I created a function to do this with each point. This may not be the most efficient way, but it works.

This function expects `pyglet.graphics.vertex_list().vertices` as input to `vertices` and any number as input to `thickness`.

```
def add_thickness(vertices,thickness):
    from math import atan,sin,cos,pi

    output = list()

    i = 2
    while i < len(vertices):
        a = vertices[i-2:i]
        b = vertices[i:i+2]

        dy = b[1]-a[1]
        dx = b[0]-a[0]

        try:
            a = -(dx/dy)
            t = atan(a)
        except:
            t = pi/2

        output.append((thickness/2)*cos(t)+b[0]);output.append((thickness/2)*sin(t)+b[1])
        output.append(-(thickness/2)*cos(t)+b[0]);output.append(-(thickness/2)*sin(t)+b[1])

        i+=2

    return output
```

Note that this function does not create points for the first vertex in the vertices list.